# Property key name in the property file

Tags: java

If I have the below property in my property file, how do I get the property key? I know how to get the value, but I am not sure how to get the key?

```
String myCountry="Australia";
```

I have this property along with others in my file. How do I get the key name (myCountry)? I would like to display it in System.out, so I need it, but I can't figure out how to get the key name, please help.

Comment: A properties file looks like `myCountry=Australia` and is probably called `names.properties`. What you show here is Java source code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of a properties file is to associate configurable values with well-known keys. You should *know* the key and use it to find which configurable value has been associated with the key. Otherwise, a Properties object is a Map, and you can iterate through all the entries:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
   System.out.prinln(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a method `public Set<String> stringPropertyNames()` in class `java.util.Properties` which is documented as:

> Returns a set of keys in this property list where the key and its corresponding value are strings, including distinct keys in the default property list if a key of the same name has not already been found from the main properties list. Properties whose key or value is not of type String are omitted.
>
> The returned set is not backed by the Properties object. Changes to this Properties are not reflected in the set, or vice versa.
>
> Returns:
>       a set of keys in this property list where the key and its corresponding value are strings, including the keys in the default property list.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you writing `String myCountry="Australia";` in your properties file ? If you can simply keep like `myCountry=Australia`. And also no need to to write `String` . 
All properties file values are `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The  [java.util.Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) Class extends the java.util.HashTable Class, so has a `keys()` method. you can use this to retrieve a list of all the keys used in the file.

To printout a key for a given value something like this will work:

```
for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
   if(entry.getValue().equals("Australia")) {
       System.out.prinln(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

This iterates through all the properties as key, value pairs until the pair with the correct value is found.

Comment: do you need to get the key for a corresponding value, or maybe to iterate across the keys until you find a given key name?

Answer (score 0):

Also this might help:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new FileInputStream("test.txt"));
    Enumeration e = p.propertyNames();

    for (; e.hasMoreElements();) {
      System.out.println(e.nextElement());

    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/GettingakeyListfromProperties.htm